# Setting a foreign key value using Entity Framework .NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-3.5

My table:

```
Employee
--------
Name
Age
Role int (foreign key)
```

How can I assign a textbox value to the Role column?

In Entity Framework 4 I would go:

```
Employee x = new Employee()
x.Role = textBox1.Text;
```

It seems I don't have the Role columns available to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF1 is not that much different on the code side to EF4. There should be two properties:

- `Role`
- `RoleReference`

In your case, you'd be setting primary key value of the latter one to avoid loading the whole `Role` entity.

So if you really don't see any of these, then your project maybe didn't compile and you're still looking at some older version of it, that doesn't have the `Role` relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a Role property available. Check your relationship between Employee and Role. Rebuild the project.